# Looking for a regex to match string with 々

Tags: regex

I have made a regex

```
[\p{IsHiragana}一-龯{}]+
```

to match a string consists of one or more Japanese kanji characters, hiragana and curly braces. So far so good, but I got surprised knowing my regex does not match the input when 々 appears in the input. See the demo [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cp%7BIsHiragana%7D%E4%B8%80-%E9%BE%AF%7B%7D%5D%2B&i=%E4%BA%BA%7B%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A8%7D%E3%80%85%7B%E3%81%B3%E3%81%A8%7D).

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You didn't mention the tool you are using (I have never seen `{IsHiragana}` as a character class), but my guess is that you have an _encoding_ problem, meaning that your Kanji character is not being treated properly.  You should be using a UTF-8 compliant regex.

Comment: This letter is outside the "Big Kahuna" regex range. `一` = `4E00` and  `龯` = `9FAF`. The `々` is `3005`. Please check your requirements.

Comment: A suggestion: maybe you can just add `\p{Lm}` to your regex? Try `[\p{IsHiragana}一-龯{}\p{Lm}]+`.

Comment: A `\p{Lm}` is a Unicode category class matching a modifier letter. See .http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm. The letter you mention belongs to this Unicode category.

Comment: just give me a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This letter is outside the "Big Kahuna" regex range. `一` = `4E00` and `龯` = `9FAF`. The `々` is `3005`.

You can add `\p{Lm}` to your regex. Use

```
 [\p{IsHiragana}一-龯{}\p{Lm}]+
```

The character you mention belongs to the modifier letter  Unicode category, so you need to add that category class to the character class.